How do I get the Hot Network Questions list back on the Stack Overflow front page?
I recently noticed that on the https://stackoverflow.com/ homepage, the hot network questions list was removed and it's basically completely destroyed my engagement with the site. I'm undecided whether that's a good or bad thing (At the very least it's removed some distractions at work), but I'd at least like to know if there's a way to get that list back on that specific page. Either that or I need to update my bookmark...

You don't, They have no intention of returning it or explaining why its gone.  The choices are either to use a tags page as your new homepage or accept it as it is

Forgive my ignorance but what is the difference between the homepage and the questions page (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions)? The questions page has it. Can you just switch to using that instead?
